# Keras for sentence classification: fig_generator batch - trainable or not?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to feed my model with batches of data incrementally as the dataset if very large. Building on the tutorial [here](https://www.kaggle.com/mschumacher/using-fasttext-models-for-robust-embeddings) I have written a data generator as below:

```
split_index = round(len(train) * 0.9)
shuffled_train = train.sample(frac=1)
df_train = shuffled_train.iloc[:split_index]
df_val = shuffled_train.iloc[split_index:]

# Convert validation set to fixed array
x_val = df_to_data(df_val)
y_val = df_val[classes].values

def data_generator(df, batch_size, gensim_embedding_model):
    """
    Given a raw dataframe, generates infinite batches of FastText vectors.
    """
    batch_i = 0 # Counter inside the current batch vector
    batch_x = None # The current batch's x data
    batch_y = None # The current batch's y data

    while True: # Loop forever
        df = df.sample(frac=1) # Shuffle df each epoch

        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            comment = row['comment_text']

            if batch_x is None:
                batch_x = np.zeros((batch_size, window_length, n_features), dtype='float32')
                batch_y = np.zeros((batch_size, len(classes)), dtype='float32')

            batch_x[batch_i] = text_to_vector(comment, gensim_embedding_model)  # LINE A
            batch_y[batch_i] = row[classes].values
            batch_i += 1

            if batch_i == batch_size:
                # Ready to yield the batch
                yield batch_x, batch_y
                batch_x = None
                batch_y = None
                batch_i = 0
```

Where 'LINE A' calls a function that looks up words in 'comment' in a pre-trained embedding model (gensim_embedding_model) and populates the vector.

I understand that this creates an embedding representation of the batch, which is fed into the model to train incrementally, and replaces the Keras EmbeddingLayer which tries to fit the embedding representation of the entire dataset into memory.

However, the Keras EmbeddingLayer has a parameter 'trainable', which can control if the parameters (i.e., word embedding weights in this case) should be treated 'as-is' or only as initial to be tuned. But using a data generator, I do not see how it is possible to set this parameter (or equivalent).

Am I right that if data generator is used in such a way, then the embedding weights are only used as-is and will not be possible to be further tuned? I.e., this is equivalent to 'trainable=False'. But with this implementation it is not possible to have 'trainable=True'?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: I've edited the post... on the second thought, I think this is equivalent to trainable=false as you feed the batch as input directly to the layers.... so it is not possible to do what's equivalent to trainable=true in the EmbeddingLayer. Is this correct?

Comment: For training, the embedding should be a part of the model, not of the generator.